# Limit sup and inf hint

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, contest-math

I have problem in finding the Limsup and liminf for the following sequences. Any hint pls?
   $(s_n) = [1-r^n]\sin \frac{n\pi}{2}$ and $(s_n) = [(-1)^n + 1]n^2$.

Comment: (1) What is that $\;r\;$ there? (2) Can you find some "special" values of $\;n\;$ for which either sequence converges?

Comment: $r$ is any real number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sequence $s_n = (1-r^n)\sin\frac{n\pi}2$, we have $|\sin\frac{n\pi}2|\leqslant 1$ for all $n$, so the limiting behavior of the sequence depends on the value of $r$. Clearly if $r=1$ then $s_n=0$ for all $n$ so $\lim_{n\to\infty} s_n=0$. If $0<|r|<1$ then $\lim_{n\to\infty}r^n=0$. Since $\sin\frac{n\pi}2=1$ for $n=1,5,9,\ldots$ and $\sin\frac{n\pi}2=-1$ for $n=3,7,11,\dots$ it should not be hard to show that $\liminf_{n\to\infty} s_n = -1$ and $\limsup_{n\to\infty}s_n=1$. If $|r|>1$ then $\lim_{n\to\infty}r^n$ doesn't exist, so the $\liminf$ and $\limsup$ of $s_n$ don't exist (unless you are using the extended real line).

For the sequence $s_n=[(-1)^n+1]n^2$, observe that $s_n = 2n^2$ for even $n$ and 0 for odd $n$. It follows immediately that $\limsup_{n\to\infty} s_n$ doesn't exist and that $\liminf_{n\to\infty} s_n=0$.

Comment: Thanks, but what are the possibilities, if using the extended real line

Comment: Then you could have $\liminf$ and/or $\limsup$ equal to $\pm\infty$. It depends on your definitions. For example, do you consider every nonempty set of real numbers to have a least upper bound (possibly $+\infty$), or do you only consider every nonempty set of real numbers that is bounded above to have a least upper bound?

Comment: Thanks for the elaboration

Comment: Math1000; Pls, having a sequence $(a_n)$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{1}^4+a_{2}^4+...+a_{n}^4}{n}=0$. Is there any justification to say that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{1}+a_{2}+...+a_{n}}{n}=0$?

Comment: It would be better to ask that in a new question since it isn't related to this one.

Comment: Ok, let put it in a new question

Comment: Here i goes; since $\frac{a_{1}^4+a_{2}^4+...+a_{n}^4}{n}$ is square summable convergent, then also $\frac{a_{1}+a_{2}+...+a_{n}}{n}$. But i am not sure whether its correct.